# Decelerate Update of UiLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, jquery-animate, uilabel

I've spent a few hours tonight trying to get two UILabels I have that are already being refreshed as a gesture is recognized (based on the translation.y and velocity.y). In the

```
if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
```

I want to animate a deceleration of the refresh of the UILabels after the gesture is complete. The UILabels are refreshed just by calling a

```
[self refreshLabels];
```

I've spent a lot of time tonight trying to do this with an infinite scrollView and tracker of the .contentOffset.y which failed miserably. I also tried to do a for and while loop in the above if statement with an animation block which also didn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions/done this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a recursive call of of refreshLabels using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:?

When the gesture ends, set a private counter and call refreshLabels.  Within refreshLabels, calculate a simple deceleration curve using the counter as the "time taken" variable and use the resulting value as the delay for the next recursive call.

Example code:

```
int counter;  // Set this value to 1 when the gesture completes

- (void)refreshLabels:(id)sender{
    // Update the labels using whatever code you have

    // This code will execute the recursive deceleration
    if (counter > -1){
        float somereasonablenumber = 0.1F;
        float delaytime = (1.0-0.1)/counter; // deceleration = (finaltime-initialtime)/timetaken
        counter++;
        if (delaytime > somereasonablenumber){
            [self performSelector:@selector(refreshLabels:) withObject:nil afterDelay:delaytime];
        } else {
            counter = -1;
        }
    }

}
```

You might need to play with the values I used for finaltime and initialtime to get the curve you want.  Right now, this code would execute on a delay curve like:

```
0.9s
0.45s
0.3s
0.225s
0.18s
0.15s
0.128571429s
0.1125s
```